# check if a URI exists?

Tags: php

How do I check if a URI exists with PHP?

I guess it will return an error code and I can check it before I use `file_get_contents`, because if I use `file_get_contents` on a link that doesn't exist, it gives me an error.

Comment: how does this question not answer itself?

Comment: it doesnt return me an error code i can do a if-statement with. it gives me an ERROR PAGE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the function [`array get_headers($url, [, int $format = 0 ])`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php), it should return `false` on failure - otherwise, you can assume the uri exists, since the web server provided you with header info.

I hope the function uses an HTTP HEAD request as opposed to a GET, which should result in a lot less traffic than in the `fopen` solutions above.

Answer (score 4):

You can send a CURL request to the uri/url. Depending on the protocol you can check the result. For HTTP you should check for the HTTP status code `404`. Check [the curl manual on php.net](http://www.php.net/curl). In some cases you can use the [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/file_exists) function.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo $info['http_code']; // gives 200
curl_close($curl);

$curl = curl_init('http://www.example.com/notfound');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo $info['http_code']; // gives 404
curl_close($curl);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
if ($_REQUEST[url] != "") {
    $result = 1;
    if (! ereg("^https?://",$_REQUEST[url])) {
        $status = "This demo requires a fully qualified http:// URL";
    } else {
        if (@fopen($_REQUEST[url],"r")) {
            $status = "This URL s readable";
        } else {
            $status = "This URL is not readable";
        }
    }
} else {
    $result = 0;
    $status = "no URL entered (yet)";
}
```

Then afterwards you can call this function using:

```
if ($result != 0) {
    print "Checking URL <b>".htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST[url])."</b><br />";
}
print "$status";
```

Comment: ereg() is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and will be removed with PHP 6. you should use preg_match() instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    $fp = @fsockopen($url, 80);
    if (false === $fp) throw new Exception('URI does not exist');
    fclose($fp); 
    // do stuff you want to do it the URI exists
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`checkdnsrr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php) does a DNS lookup. Might be of use.